# which misconfiguration causes system resets when tmpfs reaches its limits?

Tags: memory, systemd, oom

On an embedded system, there are 2 tmpfs mounts. 1GB mounted to /tmp and another 1GB mounted to /run, total RAM is 8GB. No swap is used.

If one of those reaches its limits, system resets itself.

i.e. both of the following verification causes a reset.

`cat /dev/urandom > /tmp/foo` or `cat /dev/urandom > /run/foo`

I would have expected either OOM-Killer and/or cgroups would kick in and avoid such issues.

What should have been mis-configured on kernel side and systemd side?

Edit: another test shows OOM-killer trying to do its job

```
~ # dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/somefile bs=1M count=950 ; rm /tmp/somefile
Killed
~ # free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       11789532     2487424     8363864       29148     1208604     9961408
Swap:              0           0           0
--> reset kicks in here.
```

Comment: Literally a reset? No kernel panic or anything else on your console output?

Comment: no kernel panic.

Comment: Do any other actions that occupy a lot of RAM have the same effect? Is there any equivalent of "memtest" on the platform?

Comment: There are tons of other processes going on.
OpenEmbedded provides https://pyropus.ca./software/memtester/ ? Would it do the job?

Comment: ~ # memtester 1GB
pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffffffffffff000
want 1024MB (1073741824 bytes)
got  1024MB (1073741824 bytes), trying mlock ...Killed

also gets killed and resets the target.

Comment: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/system.slice,task_memcg=/system.slice/system-standard.slice/usb.service,task=usb,pid=1734,uid=4103026
Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 1734 (watch_usbs) total-vm:617804kB, anon-rss:20586kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:4103026 pgtables:340kB oom_score_adj:0

Comment: is the watch_usbs service causing problems?

Comment: Possibly? What happens if you just manually `kill -9` that service – does this reset the system as well? (What does this service even do?)

Comment: I have killed watch_usb service. And also other 3 services watching the integrity. i.e. causing planned traceable resets. This time just another random service is killed. I guess this is OOM killer way of doing things. But I still see untraceable resets.